# RXJS: Alter objects of observable Array with inner observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm fetching an array of objects and I want to add a new property to the objects.
The value of this property should be the result of another `Observable`.

```
getDossiers = (user: IUser): Observable<Array<Record<string, any>>> => {
    return from(this.dossierSource(user).load()).pipe(
      switchMap((dossiers) => {
        const getCoordinates$ = dossiers.map(
          (
            dossier: IDossier
          ) => {
            return this.getCoordinates(
              dossier.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
            ).pipe(
              map((coordinates) => ({ ...dossier, location: coordinates })),
            );
          }
        );
        return forkJoin(getCoordinates$);
      }),
      tap((result) => console.log(result)),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  };

  getCoordinates = (address: string) => {
    return this.http
      .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
          address: address,
          key: environment.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
        },
      })
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => data.results[0].geometry.location),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          return of(null);
        })
      );
  };
```

The code from `switchMap` to the `forkJoin` results in an error :

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<any, unknown[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, Record<string, any>[]>'.
> Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>[]'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this:

```
({ ...dossier, location: coordinates })
```

With an "as" clause:

```
({ ...dossier, location: coordinates } as Record<string, any>)
```

(Or whatever it's appropriate type would be)

Comment: Still getting the same error. But doing this: "return forkJoin(getCoordinates$ as unknown[])" gets rid of the error. But feels dirty to me. It also notifies me that forkJoin is depricated implementing it like this.

Comment: I don't think you'd want to type your Observable as unknown[]. That's probably why you are getting a deprecation warning on forkJoin.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use your editor and hover over each variable and check its type to see where the type is getting "lost". Then add the appropriate as clause there. If you would be able to mock up something in Stackblitz (*not* your entire project, just the code having trouble) I could take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it was indeed a type that got lost.